# In PHP, is it possible to replicate the way that isset() suppresses warnings for undefined variables in its arguments?

Tags: php, warnings, isset, error-reporting

With the isset() function, you can pass undefined variables to its arguments without getting a warning. I was wondering if it is possible to replicate this functionality somehow.

For instance, I tried to make a function that combines isset($value) && is_array($value).

However, if I try to test it with an undefined variable, I get a "Warning: Undefined variable $somevar" warning.

```
function isset_array(mixed $value): bool
{
    if (isset($value) && is_array($value)) {
        return TRUE;
    } else {
        return FALSE;
    }
}

var_dump(isset_array($somevar));
```

I don't get the same warning with isset().

```
var_dump(isset($somevar));
```

I assume that this is some hardcoded behavior in isset().

Is it possible to replicate this behavior? Or is this some hardcoded PHP functionality that you can't mimic?

Comment: `isset` is not actually a “function”, but instead a language construct, and that is why it gets to act special.

Comment: TL;DR: no, you can't. And you shouldn't ever need to, as you should be in full control of what variables exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible workaround is to pass the variable by reference. This will prevent the "Undefined variable" notice from being generated when you pass an undefined variable to the function.

```
function isset_array(&$value): bool
{
    return isset($value) && is_array($value);
}

var_dump(isset_array($somevar));
```

Comment: That will still give a warning: https://3v4l.org/Y4IA2

Comment: The problem with this is that it creates the variable if it doesn't exist: https://3v4l.org/DNJ42